# flag comments that only beg for an answer as non-constructive

Tags: discussion, comments, flagging

I just flagged this comment (from the OP on his own post):

```
Hi Can any one help on this ?Thanks –
```

as non-constructive.

I have seen such comments before and I don't want to comment on them myself, primarily because the chance is high that the OP will jump on me and start making the begging directed to me.

Was this appropriate? I don't want to burden the mods unnecessary, but nor do I want (me and others) to have read through such irrelevancies ad infinitum.

Comment: For future reference, if you're flagging things wrong they'll get declined, and the site will tell you about it the next time you try to flag

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, the flag was appropriate. The comment was indeed non-constructive and the flag was fine.

There is no point in such comments and I think they are usually from people new to SE who consider that the same as posting "bump" in a forum. So yes, flagging them is the appropriate reaction.